# $_SERVER not returning query string

Tags: php, query-string

I'm simply trying to store the current page a user is viewing in a DB. When the page loads, I insert `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` into my DB, but only the page (e.g. `index.php?`) is showing up, without the query string (I have verified that there IS a query string in the URL).

I tried `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` with the same results.

EDIT TO ADD:
Here is the dump of $_SERVER:

```
Array
(
    . . .
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => view=scores&yr=2010&wk=1
    [REQUEST_URI] => /index.php?view=scores&yr=2010&wk=1
    . . .
)
```

So the query string is present in the array, even as part of REQUEST_URI. So my query...

```
mysql_query("insert into clickstream
               (user_id, page)
             values
               (" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ", '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) . "');")
  or die('mysql error: ' . mysql_error());
```

...should actually insert the query string twice, instead of no times!

Thoughts?

ADDED THOUGHT: Is it possible the MySQL DB strips everything from the input beyond the `?`? The field is varchar.

**UPDATE W/ PARTIAL SOLUTION:** Changing the SQL input to *just* `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` (without REQUEST_URI) successfully input the query string. Thus, it leads me to believe that either PHP or MySQL *was* stripping everything from the input string after the `?`. So the input params were correct; the result just got truncated.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Comment: Have you tested what a `var_dump($_SERVER);` has to offer?

Comment: Interesting, have you checked for the presence of a .htaccess?

Comment: Also note that POST requests do not *typically* come with a `QUERY_STRING`. (Otherwise it's an unlikely bug, as the CGI spec prescribes its presence for GET requests with parameters.)

Comment: @mario It's a GET request, and I verify that the request is going through because without it, the proper page wouldn't load. :)

Comment: Are you using a framework, or any other redirects?

Comment: @Toast I'm not sure. The site is hosted on clanteam (I think it's run by Zymic?). Is there a quick way to tell, re: your question?

Comment: You would setup a framework yourself in code, so that's probably a no.  Since it's shared hosting, I doubt you have access to apache (or whatever webserver you're using), so there's probably no extra redirects being used either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, particularly @nachito. The problem has been isolated to MySQL, not PHP. The output from PHP is correct, but MySQL is stripping everything from the URL after `?` upon insertion into the database.

Answer (score 2):

Different servers pass different `$_SERVER` globals to the page. I assume you are using Apache rather than NGINX where you might have to check that `QUERY_STRING` is defined in FASTCGI_PARAMS.

The solution is to to do like @hakre says and just see which $_SERVER key has what you want.

```
<?php
print '<pre>';
print_r($_SERVER);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: See additions to original question.

Comment: @praguian, I just checked and you need to stop whatever you're doing and [go watch this video](http://videos.code2design.com/video/play/PHP/11) before something bad happens to your application.

Comment: I updated the code to escape the input values for the SQL query to avoid SQL injection. This had already been done elsewhere in my code. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ? It has the query string as part of the output...

Comment: See additions to original question.

Comment: You should use `mysql_query("insert into clickstream (user_id, page) values (" . (int)$_SESSION['user_id'] . ", '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . "');") or die('mysql error: ' . mysql_error());` to avoid SQL injection

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that step due to the troubleshooting of the values themselves.

Comment: Your edit says that adding *just* `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` works, does adding *just* `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` work as well?

Comment: No. The result in the DB is stripped of everything after the `?` (e.g. "index.php?" instead of "index.php?query=string&bla=yada").

Comment: I've looked and still can't find anything definitive on why the string would be stripped after the `?`. Any insight would be tremendously helpful...

Comment: Instead of `mysql_query("ins...")` do a `var_dump("ins...")`. If that output looks correct try copy/pasting that query into phpMyAdmin (or similar) and see if it adds correctly there. You can (at the very least) determine whether the problem lies within PHP or MySQL at that point.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3901/discussion-between-nachito-and-praguian)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the definition of the table **clickstream** ?

If the **page** column were only 10 chars long, then we have spotted the problem :)

'index.php?' (10 chars)

To see the table structure you can issue this MySQL command:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE clickstream;
```

Comment: The `page` field is 200 char in length to avoid that very problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` was also returning an empty string. What I did was get the full URL from the server with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and then get the query string with `parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY)`.

`$queryString = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY);`